# Unique object identifiers from a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to create unique objects from each row read out of a CSV file.
The problem is creating a unique ID for each object. I thought of creating a list with all my objects first, but I don't always know how many items are contained within the CSV file. How can I generate a unique ID for each object that isn't random? I understand that I can't use a string to define an object, but I don't know how to get around that.

```
class House():
    def __init__(self,x,y,number,price):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.number = number
        self.price = price

    def __str__(self):
        result = " Latitude: {} '\n' Longitude: {} '\n' Price: {} '\n' House Number: {}".format(self.x,self.y,self.price,self.number)
        return result

def acquire_data(): 
    with open('example.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        main= "House{}".format(int(row[2]))
        main = House(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
        print row
```

Comment: Why do you want this unique id? Could you just use a number that starts at 0 and you increase for each row?

Comment: Have you heard of `enumerate`?

Comment: use a class attribute `uniq_id`

Comment: uniq_id wouldn't give me a meaningful way of labelling the objects, If I wanted to find a specific house I wouldn't have a simple way of finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT after long discussion**

```
(...)

def acquire_data(): 
    with open('example.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    houses = {}
    for row in reader:
        housenumber = int(row[2])
        house = House(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3])
        houses[housenumber] = house

    print houses[5]   # print house number 5
    print houses[5].price   # print price of house number 5
```

Comment: I want to create an object for each house based on the results returned from the CSV reader.For example:
House1 = House(1,2,1,4)
House2 = House(2,2,2,5)
etc

Comment: You can't have a variable number of named variables. You can put them all into a list though:

houses = []

for row in csv:
    houses.append(new House())

Comment: When you store all the objects into the list, there's no reference. So if I want house number 18, there's no way to call it. Unless I get the 18th element of the list, but that only works if they are in order.

Comment: In Python lists are ordered. So houses[17] will get you the 18th house (counting starts with 0).

Comment: Yes but that assumes my inputs are ordered. I could have the first input as  the 144th House, then the first element houses[0] would correspond to House number 144. Which defeats the purpose of trying to label the objects in any meaningful way.

Comment: Where does that 144 come from? Is it in the CSV? If so, is every house number in the CSV unique?

Comment: Yes it comes from the CSV, yes each house number is unique, and ideally each object would just be the house number. That way if I wanted to look up the price of house 18 I just use: House18.price

Comment: I edited the answer to use a Python dictionary. A dictionary (short "dict") is a list of unordered items which are accessible by a key. In this case I used the house number as key, but it basically can be anything.

Comment: If you define "houses" outside of the acquire_data function than you can use "houses" outside of it too. In that case acquire_data would only fill that dictionary. Or you can make the acquire_data function return the houses dictionary.

Comment: Ahhh perfect! Thank you for riding it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
class House():
    def __init__(self,x,y,number,price,id):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.number = number
        self.price = price
        self.id = id

    def __str__(self):
        result = " Latitude: {} '\n' Longitude: {} '\n' Price: {} '\n' House Number: {}".format(self.x,self.y,self.price,self.number)
        return result

def acquire_data(): 
    with open('example.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headers = reader.next()
    houses = {}
    for row in reader:
        #main= "House{}".format(int(row[2]))
        tmp = House(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],id)
        houses[id] = tmp
        id += 1
        print row
    return houses
```

Comment: At the end of the for loop I'd end up with only one object, since you're over-writing "main" every time the index increases.